# How to solve java.io.IOException: Stream closed and java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, jsp, servlets

**I want to send some command to server and server will send acknowledgment for the same.Command will get triggered when button on jsp page is clicked.Problem is server is getting the command but client is not able to accept ack due to above two exceptions.**

This is my client sending command and receiving ack

```
public void Stop_Exposure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //response.setContentType( "text/html" ) ;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    //Socket socket = null;
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.13.189", 1026);
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String command = "Stop_Exposure";
        //  String sendMessage = command + "\n";
        bw.write(command);
        //  bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+command);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Control_Panel.jsp").forward(request, response);

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);    

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //..    br.close();
        //..    bw.flush();
        //..    bw.close();
        //Closing the socket
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my server code

```
class Socket2 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss1 = new ServerSocket(1026);// ("192.168.13.189",1025);
            while (true) {
                Socket s1 = ss1.accept();
                InputStream is1 = s1.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr1 = new InputStreamReader(is1);
                String ack = null;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr1);
                String command = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received..." + command);

                // Sending the response back to the client.
                OutputStream os = s1.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                if (command.equals("Stop_Exposure")) {
                    ack = "Ok";
                    bw.write(ack);
                } else {
                    ack = "Error";
                    bw.write(ack);
                }
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + ack);
                // .. bw.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
Dec 13, 2017 1:34:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:171)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
 at org.apache.jsp.Control_005fPanel_jsp._jspService(Control_005fPanel_jsp.java:6294)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
 at Stop_Exposure.doPost(Stop_Exposure.java:61)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
 at Stop_Exposure.doPost(Stop_Exposure.java:61)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:182)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
 at org.apache.jsp.Control_005fPanel_jsp._jspService(Control_005fPanel_jsp.java:6294)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.ensureOpen(JspWriterImpl.java:187)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:105)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:171)
 ... 39 more
```

Comment: And, what have you done so far?

Comment: Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm able to send command and server is able to send ack but client is not able to move ahead to receive ack because of above two exceptions. Above is the code for client.

Comment: Added code for both client and server.

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: 'How to solve java.io.IOException: Stream closed': don't close a stream or a socket and then continue to use it; 'and java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred when flushing data?' you will have to provide the stack trace for that.

Comment: @Sudheera Added full stack trace

Comment: @EJP Added full stack trace

Comment: @EJP Tried running the code by not closing streams and sockets, but error is same.

Comment: This stack trace has nothing to do with the code you posted. The stack trace comes from the `doPost()` method of a *Servlet* or JSP called `Stop_Exposure`, not a *method* called `Stop_Exposure()`.

Answer (score 1):

The exception shown in the stacktrace is not happening in this code at all.  As you can see, it occurs in Jasper code while attempting to release the PageContext and flush the **response** output stream.  The Socket streams and the socket server code are not involve.

The exception actually seems to be caused by something that a method called `Stop_Exposure.doPost` is doing.  That's not *this* code.

The other thing is that your `Stop_Exposure` method doesn't make a lot of sense:

- If the aim is to process the stuff you get from your socket service asynchronously, this is a bad way to do it (IMO).  The call to `forward` is not going to return until the JSP has finished formatting the response.  Then *this* code will wait until the response from the socket server arrives before releasing the request thread.
- You open the response writer, but you don't actually use it.  Instead, you are writing stuff to the webcontainer's standard output.  That will go to a log file somewhere ... not the browser that sent the HTTP request.
- If you did attempt to write to the response writer after the `forward` call returned, you would get an error.  The spec says:

  > "Before the forward method of the RequestDispatcher interface returns without exception, the response content must be sent and committed, and closed by the servlet container."

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to remove the errors but now problem is my server is not accepting the command and not able to send ack even if process has started.

Comment: Write a new question.  Make sure that you include a clear description of the problem, and the **relevant** code.  In other words, learn from the mistakes you made in asking this one!  (Hint: if you ask the question *properly* the first time you are less likely to be downvoted .....)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling writer.close(); after you've done writing to it. Once a stream is closed, it can not be written to again. Usually, the way I go about implementing this is by moving the close out of the write to method.

```
public void writeToFile(){
    String file_text= pedStatusText + "     " + gatesStatus + "     " +  DrawBridgeStatusText;
      try {
         writer.write(file_text);
          writer.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

And add a method cleanUp to close the stream.

```
public void cleanUp() {
     writer.close();
}
```

This means that you have the responsibility to make sure that you're calling cleanUp when you're done writing to the file. Failure to do this will result in memory leaks and resource locking.